# Do Objects, Results, etc. retain their Realm instance?

Tags: swift, realm

I can't seem to find an answer to the question anywhere.

Am I allowed to create a `Realm` instance inside a function, fetch some objects, and return those objects? Will this cause the `Realm` for the objects to be deallocated, and if so, will my objects then be invalidated? Or will the objects retain their `Realm` until they are released?

```
func getObject() -> MyObject {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.objects(MyObject.self).first!
}

let object = getObject()

object.isInvalidated // What will this return?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this for myself after posing this question.

An `Object` does seem to retain it's realm. In the example from the question, the object is not invalidated and `object.realm` is not `nil`. You can create a `Realm` instance and return objects form that `Realm` without retaining the `Realm`. Once all objects in the `Realm` are released, the `Realm` should also be released.